# Why basename with a suffix doesn't work in a subshell when used with find?

Tags: bash, find, subshell, command-substitution

The following command doesn't do the subtitution, why?

```
find ./ -name "*.dng" -exec echo `basename \{\} .dng`  \;
```

but this command work:

```
find ./ -name "*.dng" -exec basename \{\} .dng  \;
```

What I'm actually trying to do is to find all the dng in my hard drive and do:

```
touch -c -r {basename}.RW2  {basename}.dng
```

Comment: Because bash first runs `basename \{\} .dng` and with its output it then runs your `find` command.

Comment: This needs more details. Are RW2 files in the same directory as dng files, or are they all in the directory where you issue find from? What exactly do you need `basename` for?

Comment: @oguz Ismail, RW2 files are in the same directory as dng files. I use basename to remove the prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following command doesn't do the subtitution, why?
>
> ```
> find ./ -name "*.dng" -exec echo `basename \{\} .dng`  \;
> ```

As Cyrus already said in [his comment](/questions/62355444/why-basename-with-a-prefix-dont-work-in-a-subshell-when-used-with-find#comment110281686_62355444), bash expands `` `basename \{\} .dng` `` to `{}` before invoking `find`; so what find receives is just `echo {}`, it doesn't see `` `basename \{\} .dng` `` part.

> What I'm actually trying to do is to find all the dng in my hard drive and do:
>
> ```
> touch -c -r {basename}.RW2 {basename}.dng
> ```

Assuming each reference file (`*.RW2`) is in the same directory as corresponding `.dng` file, I would do it like this:

```
find . -name '*.dng' -exec sh -c '
for dng do
  touch -c -r "${dng%.*}.RW2" "$dng"
done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Can you explain again what ```_ {} +``` do?

Comment: {} and + are $1 and $2 ? Or it's sh parameters?

Comment: @Fractale `{}` is replaced with selected files by find, `+` means *run this command with as many arguments as possible*. Just check `man find`, it's all written there.